# SystemVerilog Concurrent Assertion Sequence Dynamic Length

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, verification, system-verilog-assertions, synopsys-vcs

I have an array of length x. A signals output for a given testbench will be each value in the array in its respective order from 0:x-1.

In my problem in particular, the array is filter coefficients and the testbench is the impulse response.
The test needs to be self-checking, which will require a sequence with dynamic length, as the coefficients will change from test to test.

The sequence I would like should look something like this:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  assert_sequence : assert property (    
        (data_out == array_1[0])
    |=> (data_out == array_1[1])
    |=> (data_out == array_1[2]) 
    |=> (data_out == array_1[3]) 
    |=> (data_out == array_1[4]) 
    |=> (data_out == 0) ) 
      $info("Seen the sequence");
    else
      $error("Sequence was incorrect");  
  end
```

Can this be possible to do dynamically? I've tried a genvar for loop but it throws errors. I've searched the forums and can't find anything that meets my requirement like so.

Possibly something like this could give the right answer?

```
    always @(posedge clk) begin
  assert_sequence : assert property (    
        (data_out == array1[0][0])

  for(genvar i = 1; i < 5, i++) begin
    |=> (data_out == array1[i])
  end

    |=> (data_out == 0) ) 
      $info("Seen the sequence");
    else
      $error("Sequence was incorrect");  
  end
```

Comment: A very interesting problem. SVA wouldn't be my natural first choice for checking this. And BTW: daisy-chaining _implication operators_ (`|=>`) probably doesn't mean what you think it means. It doesn't answer this probably, but nevertheless I think you should be using a simple `##1`, ie `assert_sequence : assert property (    
    <some_trigger> |=>    (data_out == array_1[0])
    ##1 (data_out == array_1[1])
    ##1 (data_out == array_1[2])  ... `

Comment: I can't (off the top of my head) think of how you'd put a loop in an SVA assertion. You could have a mega assertion that checks every sample of your impulse response individually and ORs each one with some kind of mask array, eg `... ##1 (data_out == array_1[3]) || mask[3] ##1 ...` and you'd make all the "extra" elements of the mask array (that are not required for a shorter impulse response) 1 (ie TRUE). But, I'd think I'd write this check in SystemVerilog not SVA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments are very useful and had notes of the direction I have taken to resolve this. Just revisited the problem and came up with this un-elegant solution.

```
for(genvar i = 1; i < 5; i++) begin
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    assert_sequence : assert property (
                                       (data_out == array1[0])
                               |-> ##i (data_out == array1[i])
                               |-> ##(5-i) (data_out == 0) //This line prevents error 
                                                                  //as my coefficients are symmetric
                                    )
      $info("Impulse response Coefficient %0d seen", i);
  else
      $error("Impulse response Coefficient %0d not seen", i);
  end
end
```

This code creates multiple assertions, and describes that when I see the first coefficient, in i clock cycles I expect to see the (i+1) coefficient, and due to my problems symmetry, in (5-i) clock cycles I will see a 0.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, SVA is probably not the natural choice here. However, indeed an interesting problem so had a little think:

Have you tried using recursive properties? Something along the lines of:

```
property check_sequence(coefficients);
  (data_out == coefficients[0]) ##0
    ((coefficients.size() == 1) or 
     (##1 check_sequence(coefficients[1:coefficient.size()]));
endproperty

assert_label: check_sequence(array_1);
```

would still need a trigger - not specified in the original q.

Whether it's the most efficient or readable solution is another matter.